# How to display images from Cloudinary/attachinary

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I'm currently working on a way to display images from Cloudinary. Those images are attached to the `Declaration model`.

Here's what I came up with :

```
<% cache @declarations do %>
  <table class="tableau_stats">
    <th>IMEI</th>
    <th>Prénom</th>
    <th>Nom</th>
    <th>Adresse</th>
    <th>Code postal</th>
    <th>Ville</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Numéro de téléphone</th>
    <th>Créé le</th>
    <th>Panne</th>
    <th>MDP Icloud</th>
    <th>MDP</th>

    <% @declarations.each do |declaration| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= declaration.imei %></td>
        <td><%= declaration.firstname %></td>
        <td><%=declaration.lastname%></td>
        <td><%=declaration.address %></td>
        <td><%=declaration.postal_code %></td>
        <td><%=declaration.city%></td>
        <td><%= declaration.email %></td>
        <td><%= declaration.phone_number %></td>
        <td><%= declaration.created_at.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></td>
        <td><%= declaration.type_outage %></td>
        <td><%= declaration.icloud_password %></td>
        <td><%= declaration.unlock_code %></td>
        <td><%= cl_image_path(declaration.facture) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

But all I have is a broken image and a link below.

My ENV are stocked into my `application.yml` according to the figaro gems.

What am I doin wrong ?

thanks.

**UPDATE**

Here's what it returns me

http://res.cloudinary.com/prs/image/upload/%23%3CAttachinary::File:0x00007f9dd2130408%3E

My `declaration.rb` looks like this :

```
class Declaration < ApplicationRecord
  has_attachment :facture, accept: [:pdf]
  validates_size_of :facture, maximum: 15.megabytes, message: "Le fichier doit être inférieur à 15 megabytes"
  validates :facture, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Can you please add source code of the generated image tag?

Comment: Yes, i'll edit my question.

Comment: Does it looks better like this @MrShemek ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify how `facture` is defined within your declaration object, but it does look as if Rails thinks it is an `Attachinary::File` object.

Would `cl_image_path(declaration.facture.path)` work better for you?

Comment: Hi @Scott, thanks for answering. I'll update my question in a few minute. 
But your suggestion still not working :/ I have the same return I've posted.

Comment: Hmm. Looking at the Cloudinary helper internals, whatever you pass in as the first argument has `#to_s` called upon it, which is what is causing the output of `#<Attachinary::File:0x00....>` when you pass the whole object in to it. I'm looking at my own code base (where members have a Cloudinary-powered `avatar` property), and `cl_image_path(member.avatar)` produces the same "bad" URL format you've reported. `cl_image_path(member.avatar.path)`, however, works a treat.

Comment: Hum I see. Thanks for those explanation. But I just noticed something. There's no facture attribute in my declaration schema, so ```factures``` are not linked to any declarations object ..